# What's the difference between $\lambda$ abstraction and explicit definition?

Tags: type-theory

I understand that these are two ways of defining elements of a function types.

The HoTT book even says that

$f ≡ (λx. f(x)).$ (The uniqueness principle for function types)

I am very confused and I don't understand what even hypothetical differences between a function defined explicitly and one defined using lambda abstraction might be.

Comment: What do you mean by "a function defined explicitly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I don't think it's helpful to think of these as very different things, but I think I can clarify the distinction the HoTT authors are making.

In type theory such as HoTT (really typed $\lambda$-calculus generally), $\lambda$-abstraction is the formal operation taking an open term $\phi(x):B$, where $x$ has type $A$, to $\lambda x.\phi(x):A\to B$.

In what the HoTT authors are calling "explicit definition", they're simply giving an abbreviated name to the open term; "$f(x) :\equiv \phi(x)$" just means "$f(x)$ is just an abbreviation for the term $\phi(x)$"; note that "$\lambda x.\phi(x)$" is actually a term in the language of the type theory, while the abbreviation of terms is properly a metatheoretic device.
From here the authors want us to trust that such an open term corresponds to an element, which we can call $f$, of the appropriate function type, though they don't explain how they make that formal right away. Morally, we can afford not to be too formal here because we *know* that our category of types is going to be Cartesian closed$^\dagger$, so however we decide to package that in the type theory, open terms like those above *will* correspond to an element of $A\to B$.

But the HoTT authors' formalize it on p.30 immediately after introducing the uniqueness principle you quote: $f$ is defined as an abbreviation for the $\lambda$-abstract---i.e. $f:\equiv \lambda x.\phi(x)$. Having these $\lambda$-abstracts available is precisely the feature of the type theory that justifies the informal practice the authors call "explicit definition"---it allows you to always demonstrate the existence of the desired term of a function type.

In a more colloquial sense, both versions are perfectly explicit because you need to actually give this term $\phi(x)$ to define the function, which will usually be composed of more basic operations on terms. But the difference between the things given the names "explicit definition" and "$\lambda$-abstraction" in the HoTT book is one of formality, though both start from the same data.

$^\dagger$ Edit: As Derek Elkins points out, the rules that would make the category of types strictly Cartesian (closed) are flagged in the HoTT book as optional, so the above statement is actually inaccurate. The weaker alternatives, such as being *weakly* Cartesian (closed), or Cartesian (closed) *up to a contractible space of choices*, still result in a category that justifies our intuition that open terms ought to have associated function terms and *vice versa*.

Comment: One should note that your discussion relates to syntactic abbreviations for lambda terms and is orthogonal to the uniqueness principle for function types. I do believe the abbreviation aspect is what's confusing the OP, but for clarity everything you've said would be just as true if the uniqueness principle for function types didn't hold except the Cartesian closure stuff which actually isn't true anyway because the HoTT book doesn't assume a (judgmental) uniqueness principle for pair types so our category need not even be Cartesian, let alone Cartesian closed.

Comment: @DerekElkins - I didn't read the question as actually having anything to do with the uniqueness principle at all--it just seems to pop up randomly in the middle of the real question--so I don't see any need to address it. I will, however, revisit the issue about Cartesian closedness....

Comment: I wasn't saying you needed to address it. I was just pointing out (for others) that the inclusion in the question is (probably) a bit of a red herring which is why your answer *didn't* address it. I probably could've been clearer about that though.

Comment: @DerekElkins - Gotcha.

Comment: Actually, there's a subtle point here. The category of types will be Cartesian closed if function uniqueness holds, regardless of whether pair types are strict products. But since, in the "formal type theory" appendix, the authors still call the uniqueness principles optional even for function types, I've made a note to address your comment.